# How do i get changed value of a single checkbox in requestparam and pass it to ModelAndView in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, http-request-parameters

html file:

```
     <html>
   <body>
      <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="postcheckbox" />
        demo checkbox
    </label>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get the value of changed state of checkbox in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

By using Js

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name=postcheckbox]");

checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    console.log("Checkbox is checked..");
    //pass to model

  } else {
    console.log("Checkbox is not checked..");
    //pass to model

  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! But I am new to spring boot so can you tell me how do i send the data from javascript to my controller method..

Comment: Can you help me with this please..

Comment: no bro , im not good at spring boot